# Check array contain elements mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework

```
ArrayList<String> labels = (ArrayList) payload.get("labels");
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
      match(Criteria.where("user_id").is(id).and("page_id").is(pageId).and("labels").in(labels)),
                sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "meta_data.user_data.time"),
                group(Fields.fields().and("first_name", "$meta_data.user_data.first_name").and("last_name", "$meta_data.user_data.last_name").and("profile_pic", "$meta_data.user_data.profile_pic").and("user_id", "$user_id").and("labels", "$labels").and("access_times","$meta_data.access_times"))
      );

AggregationResults<UsersMongoResult> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "chatuser_log", UsersMongoResult.class);
```

in document labels array is something like this `labels: ["123", "456"]`

when ArrayList labels = ["123"] result matched 
but when ArrayList labels = ["123", "789"] it also matched that document.

How to overcame this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of the [in-operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):

> If the field holds an array, then the $in operator selects the documents whose field holds an array that contains at least one element that matches a value in the specified array (e.g. , , etc.)

If you want to match an array that contains all specified values, you need the [all-operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)

```
where("user_id").is(id).and("page_id").is(pageId).and("labels").all(labels))
```