# MongoTemplate Query array that match at least the values I'm passing

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongotemplate, nosql-aggregation

If I have a Documents defined as

```
[
  {
    "title": "title",
    "tags": [ "cool", "amazing", "funny" ]
  },
  {
    "title": "another title",
    "tags": [ "nice", "amazing", "funny" ]
  }
]
```

I'd like to be able to query with MongoTemplate in order to pass a list of values like ["cool","amazing"] and have in return the first collection above, not the second.
For what I mean to achieve, the **$in** condition doesn't seems enough.
I tried with the **$all** condition and from the Mongo console it works as I need, but in my code something isn't working and it takes forever for my query to elaborate. With the **$in** operator my code goes fast, instead.
My method in my repository (for other reasons, I have to do an aggregation as below):

```
public Page<MyDocument> findByProperties(String title, List<ObjectId> tags, Pageable page) {
        final List<Criteria> criteria = new ArrayList<>();
        Aggregation aggregation = null;

        
        if (title != null && !title.isEmpty()) {
            criteria.add(Criteria.where("title").is(title));
        }
        
        if (tags != null && !tags.isEmpty()) {
            criteria.add(Criteria.where("MyBook.tags").all(tags));
        }

        if (!criteria.isEmpty()) {
            aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                    Aggregation.lookup("from_collection", "_id", "idParent", "MyBook"),
                    Aggregation.unwind("MyBook"),
                    Aggregation.match(new Criteria().andOperator(criteria.toArray(new Criteria[0]))),
                    Aggregation.skip(page.getOffset()),
                    Aggregation.limit(page.getPageSize()),
                    Aggregation.sort(page.getSort())
            );
        } else {
            aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                    Aggregation.lookup("from_collection", "_id", "idParent", "MyBook"),
                    Aggregation.unwind("MyBook"),
                    Aggregation.skip(page.getOffset()),
                    Aggregation.limit(page.getPageSize()),
                    Aggregation.sort(page.getSort())
            );
        }

        List<MyDocument>  results  = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "my_document", MyDocument.class).getMappedResults();

        return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(results, page,
                () -> (long)results.size());
    }
```

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44671983/15831579) answer, I tried with

```
criteria.add(Criteria.where("MyBook.tags").in(tags).all(tags));
```

But nothing changed, the query takes forever and not with the expected output.
Any ideas please? Thank you!

Comment: I think you just need to pass the `criteria` variable to the `Aggregation.match(`.

Comment: Hi @prasad_ , I'm testing the case where criteria is not empty: in the first if there is the Aggregation.match()

Answer (score 0):

To find if tags array field contains all the members of youe array, your can use the bellow, if you need it to be in aggregation pipeline use the second.

In your query you have more stages, and more code, if you want to ask more if you can give example data and expected output in JSON, and what you want to do, so people can help.

Query1

- find using `$all` operator

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vGYu3VAbDdd)

```js
db.collection.find({"tags": {"$all": ["cool","amazing"]}})
```

Query2

- aggregation solution with set difference

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k3oAamXUdec)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": 
    {"$expr": 
      {"$eq": [{"$setDifference": [["cool", "amazing"], "$tags"]}, []]}}}])
```

Comment: Hi Takis, thank you for your tips! What I need is to do it with Java, not via Mongo console where it already works. With MongoTemplate I'd have to use a Projection, and in my case I'd rather stick with the Aggregation. For the code examples, I just need to join two collections (Aggregation) and query on an Array present in the "MyBook" collection which I join into